# Appending both stdout and stderr to file

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, stdio

I have this:

```
nohup_ntrs(){
  nohup_file="$HOME/teros/nohup/stdio.log"
  mkdir -p "$(dirname "$nohup_file")";
  echo " ------------- BEGIN $(date) -------------- " >> "$nohup_file"
  nohup "$@" &>> "$nohup_file"
  echo " ------------- END $(date) -------------- " >> "$nohup_file"
}
```

but this syntax is wrong:

```
 nohup "$@" &>> "$nohup_file"
```

I was trying to use the >> operator for append but also send stderr there.
My guess is that the only way to do this is this:

```
 nohup "$@" 2>&1 >> "$nohup_file"
```

is there a less verbose way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&>>` is correct syntax in the `bash` shell to redirect both the standard output stream and the standard error stream to a file in append mode.

What I think may be happening is that you run the script using `sh`, which on your system is not `bash`.  Or, you are running a `bash` older than release 4.0, which is the first release that supported `&>>`.

The other way to do this, which is standard compliant, is to use `>>file 2>&1`.  In your case,

```bash
nohup "$@" >>"$nohup_file" 2>&1
```

There is no *shorter* way to do this in a standard compliant `sh` shell.

Note that what you suggest, `2>&1 >>file`, is back to front and would not send the standard error stream to the file but to wherever the standard output stream *originally* went.  Redirections are handled in a left-to-right manner, so *your* redirection would first send standard error to wherever standard output goes, and *then* redirect standard output to the file in append mode.  In other words: the second redirection, `>>file` would not change where standard error goes, so it goes where standard output originally went due to the preceding `2>&1`.

---

An alternative way to write your code would be

```sh
nohup_ntrs () {
  nohup_file="$HOME/teros/nohup/stdio.log"
  mkdir -p "$(dirname "$nohup_file")"

  {
    printf ' ------------- BEGIN %s -------------- \n' "$(date)"
    nohup "$@"
    printf ' ------------- END %s ---------------- \n' "$(date)"
  } >>"$nohup_file" 2>&1
}
```

This reduces the number of redirections to a single one by grouping the commands whose output should be redirected in curly braces and redirecting that *compound command* as a whole.

Comment: yeah I guess on bash version 3, the `&>>` operator doesn't work,  but bash 4 recognizes it or something

Comment: btw, just curious, why does the `2>&1` go after the `>>` operator, not before? I think there is a reason for that but idk

Comment: @AlexanderMills I tried to explain the significance of the ordering. There are other questions on this site regarding this. See e.g. [Order of redirections](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/37660) and [understand a sequence of redirections](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/16360)

Answer (score 0):

`nohup "$@" 2>&1 | tee "$nohup_file"`

Or you can open file descriptor in script with `exec` and redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` to this descriptor

Comment: This would truncate and overwrite the output file. I think you may have wanted to use `tee -a`.  This would, however, arguably not be "less verbose".

Comment: That's a bit of a useless use of `tee`, but if you do that, you may want to `> /dev/null` it so you don't get the output on the terminal.